# How to see/install pg_activity for the crunchy data postgres operator?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I have setup an Rancher (RKE) (kuberbetes) for my application.

and application using the postgres so i have setup Crunchydata postgres operator and create postgres cluster using that.

everything fine but now i want to see the pg_activity for my postgresql.

how i can see the activity of whole postgres ?

Answer (score 0):

you use the monitoring tools in rancher to monitor the Postgres.

apart from that you can SSH inside the respective pod of the database and use the cli command and check the output.

In rancher, you can also use the client tool to connect with the rancher and run the cli command to check the pg_activity.

Client docker image : https://hub.docker.com/r/jbergknoff/postgresql-client/

you can also deploy the GUI docker client on rancher and use it

GUI postgress client : https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/

GUI Example : [https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-database-sessions#:~:text=Using%20pgAdmin,all%20connected%20sessions%20(3)](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-database-sessions#:%7E:text=Using%20pgAdmin,all%20connected%20sessions%20(3)).